# convert '19th October 2018' into date in Presto/SQL

Tags: sql, presto, redash, periscope

I have a column of strings which have been extracted from email content. The strings are in the format:-

```
Tuesday 12th March 2019
```

I can use split_part to drop the Tuesday (anything up to and including 'day' is cut) 
but that's a lot more difficult for the day of the month part. I can convert this to a date if the 'th' (or 'rd' or 'st') is gone from the day of the month but I can't quite get there.

Any advice gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this :

```
date_parse('Tuesday 12th March 2019','%W %D %M %Y')
```

Depending on if the prestosql doc is up to date, this might not work because it is said :

> Warning
>   The following specifiers are not currently supported: %D %U %u %V %w %X

[presto sql doc](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse)

EDIT : In addition to gordon's answer you could try to use :

```
date_parse(regexp_replace('Tuesday 12th March 2019','(\d+)((th|rd|nd|st) )','$1 '),'%W %d %M %Y')
```

Comment: Yeah, it falls down on `%D` unfortunately. :(

Comment: @BarryEvansSee my edit which might upgrade gordon's answer

Comment: Brilliant, that's what I was looking for!

Thank you both very much, appreciate the help!

Comment: Also you might prefer %e instead of %d because %d is for day like 01, 02 etc. %e is for day written like 1,2, etc. I think this will be better because your date should be 1st and not 01st ;) Have fun ! Glad to help !

Answer (score 1):

There are a finite number of suffixes, so how about a brute force appraoch:

```
date_parse(replace(replace(replace(replace(substr(str, position(' ' in str) + 1
                                          ), 'st', ''
                                  ), 'nd', ''
                          ), 'rd', ''
                  ), 'th'),
           '%d %M %Y'
          )
```

It would be much simpler if `date_parse()` supported `%D`, but apparently it does not.

Comment: date_parse was the first thing I tried.

It might just have to be brute force ... but odd there isn't a native way of doing this!

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ah, yes ... I had considered brute force then realised I'd be taking the 'st' out of August. Can still be done I suppose by adding in a `case when` ... meh!

Comment: And I didn't read properly because you `substr`'d it. 

Thank you, I think that's the best approach for now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I took the advice from both users above which helped me towards the solution. The final bit of code looked like this:-

date(date_parse(trim(regexp_replace(split_part(split_part(split_part(`my_data`,`split_here` ,2),'`split_here_2`,1),`split_here_3`,2),'(\d+)((th|rd|nd|st) )','$1 ')),'%e %M %Y'))

which returned:-

2018-11-04

2019-04-06

2018-11-02

2019-09-19

2019-07-12

2018-11-04

2018-09-29

2018-10-19

2018-11-02

Thanks again for the help!!